# SQL Server datatypes nvarchar and varchar are incompatible error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've inherited a C# app which I've converted to vb. I get one error which as far as I can see has nothing to do with the conversion.

I have a SQL statement which is....

```
SELECT   ResolverID AS ddlValue, ResolverTeam & ' | ' & ResolverPerson AS ddlText 
FROM     dbo.TblResolvers 
ORDER BY ResolverTeam, ResolverPerson;
```

When this runs I get the error:

> *The data types nvarchar and varchar are incompatible in the boolean
>   AND operator.*

In the table both `ResolverTeam` and `ResolverPerson` are specified as (`nvarchar(255`), `null`)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Why it specifically talking about `varchar` is because `' | '` is a `varchar` literal. If you want an `nvarchar` literal, use `N' | '`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try replacing the `&` for a `+`; by the looks of it, what you're trying to do is to concatenate 2 columns. Something you do need to be careful about is that `nvarchar` is double the size of regular `varchar`, which means there are chars in `nvarchar` that are not in the `varchar` table.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [**`+`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) for string concatenation:

```
SELECT 
  ResolverID AS ddlValue, 
  ResolverTeam + ' | ' + ResolverPerson AS ddlText 
FROM dbo.TblResolvers 
Order By ResolverTeam, ResolverPerson;
```

> Why am I getting this error?

You were getting that error, because of the [**`&`** operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx), which is the *Bitwise AND*.

Answer (score 4):

To concatenate strings in MSSQL you should use `+`

```
SELECT ResolverID AS ddlValue, 
  ResolverTeam + ' | ' + ResolverPerson AS ddlText 
    FROM dbo.TblResolvers Order By ResolverTeam, ResolverPerson;
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this a concatenation attempt? `ResolverTeam & ' | ' & ResolverPerson`

`&` is the bitwise operator `AND`, replace it with `+` and see what happens.